# DontDestroyOnLoad Object In a toggle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an DontDestroyOnLoad audio,and i want to mute it with a toggle in the other scene(where the audio activates as a Dontdestroyonload object) How can I import/put Dontdestroyonload audio into a On Value Changed toggle that is in the other scene?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I could only imagine an implementation, based on your infos, that looks something like this:

```
//The audio to play
public AudioSource audio;
//The toggle
public bool play;

void Update()
{
    //Play if should AND it is stopped
    if(play && !audio.isPlaying)
        audio.Play(0);
    //Pause if should AND it is playing
    else if(!play && audio.isPlaying)
        audio.Pause();
}
```

This is just a very small EXAMPLE on how it could be realized.
The play bool would need to be manually changed

Comment: how can i put my audio in the public AudioSource if it is on Dontdestroyonload,for example-in 1st scene there is my audio playing, when the scene changes to 2nd scene the audio turns to Dontdestroyonload,and i have to put the audio in the 2nd scene's toggle